# ACF error on wp-login.php

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress 4.3.1 and using ACF (Advanced custom fields) 5.3.0. I have following errors in "wp-login.php".

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 319

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 320

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 325

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 326

Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 's.t.r.r.e.v' not found or invalid function name in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 327

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php:319) in /www/htdocs/w00e3b8f/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/field.php on line 328

Do you have any idea how to resolve these errors ?

Comment: It sounds like your php file might be saved in a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBCS encoding which is not supported by your server.  Did you edit and upload that field.php file?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I didn't edit that file, just uploaded while installing the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried downloading and viewing that specific file?  Not sure but it could be malware or a rootkit.  I cant see why the official ACF PRO would need to use the `strrev` function but I dont have the official file to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a hacked version of the plugin! Delete it, or go through the code and clean it up.

[strrev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) is is php function for reversing a string, it is commonly used in hacking schemes.